# In jhipster not able use hash '#' in url but question mark '?' is working fine

Tags: angularjs, url, jhipster

In jhipster I am not able use hash '#' in url but question mark '?' is working fine.

For example:

> www.basicurl.com/firstname.lastname#/demo/test

It removes "firstname.lastname" from url, which becomes www.basicurl.com#/demo/test. But when I use a question mark it becomes:

> basicurl.com/firstname.lastname?/demo/test

This works fine.

My code for profile page mapping for firstname and lastname is as below:

```
@RestController
public class ProfileMappingResource {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{firstName}.{lastName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @Timed
    public void loadProfilePageMapping(@PathVariable String firstName,@PathVariable String lastName,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

        String newURI = "/dist" + "/profile.html";
        try {
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(newURI);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ? splits the remainder of the URL into a parameter string (typically ?param1=value1&param2=value2 etc), and therefore doesn't use it as a path variable.